# Accidently deleted something from usr/bin (Mac)

Tags: c, macos

Today I wanted to compile some C-Code when VsCode gave me an include-path error. I thought that was odd, since I didn't remember changing anything there. So I tried to compile my code with C-Lion, but right after opening C-Lion, there was another error-message telling me, that it wasn't able to compile a small test-programm and gave me a usr/bin/cc - broken error message.

After trying to figure out where the problem was I remebered that I was cleaning up my Mac the other day and deleted folders that I thought would belong to the RiotClient, that I just uninstalled. My guess is that I deleted some folders that I shouldn't have deleted ...
And of course I already emptied my trash bin.

As I am using clang to compile (Vs-Code) I tried to check for my clang version (using clang --version in the terminal), which again ended in a usr/bin - error message (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun)

Is there any way to get out of this mess or do I need to reset my mac completely.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you running Time Machine with regular backups?  If so, you can use that to recover the files.  If not, you probably need to reinstall XCode, if that's the compiler you're using.  However, this is not really a question about programming and it really isn't on-topic for SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Stack Overflow is not just for programming questions. It is also for [“software tools commonly used by programmers”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Getting your developer environment configured correctly qualifies.

Comment: But this is more of a system administration question than a programming question and probably belongs on Server Fault or SuperUser rather than SO, @EricPostpischil, and probably does not belong on Ask Different.  However, you are at liberty to continue disagreeing with me — other people can take sides if they wish, or simply ignore the whole storm in a teacup.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Maybe it is a system administration question, maybe it is not. Installations of some developer tools interfere with each other, so OP’s hypothesis they deleted something from `/usr/bin` may be incorrect. Or, even if they did, a solution may be to reinstall a particular tool rather than to restore some unknown thing from a backup. And programmers on Stack Overflow are more familiar with developer tool problems than general system administrators are. Certainly the question does involve software tools commonly used by programmers, and punting it is overly picky.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sadly I am not running Time Machine. But I reinstalled the XCoode Command Line Tools. It seems like the MacOS updated mixed something up, which also seems to be a known thing to happen. VS-Code now works the same as before but C-Lion still doesn't compile. I am installing XCode from the AppStore now :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wil check out the other forums you brought up. To be honest: I kinda panicked and SO was **the forum** that popped in my head.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, C-Lion wasn't working because the project folder was "corrupted". Creating a new project after reinstalling the XCode Command Line Tools works just fine. So that seems to be the solution.

Comment: SO is not a forum. Also @JonathanLeffler is correct and this question is off topic

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

As @JonathanLeffler suggested, the solution is to reinstall the XCode Command Line Tools. It seems like the latest MacOS update mixed something up, which seems to be a common thing to happen (see comments).

[I followed this guide](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/7.html) to reinstall it :)

It doesn't seem to be necessary to download the XCode IDE as I thought haha.